# Can't create table 'basque30.newreferral' (errno: 150)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

First of all thanks for the help and the words of support.
As I am learning MySQL from the web I know I'm going to make many errors and thanks in advance for your patience and understanding.

I'm making the project based in Java which is then creating a MySQL Database and Tables.
Generally it is going well, until I have encountered this problem. It has given me the biggest headache so far. I read many articles on the error 150. I have read [error 150 on MySQL site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) and I think that I have fulfilled the ten reasons why a error 150 occurs.

The call that I'm making is calling is creating each Table. Here are some of the Tables which are covering the problem that I'm having.

This is the WorkCalendar Table

```
    private String workCalandar = "CREATE TABLE WorkCalendar ("
        + "WorkCalendarIdNo INT(64) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
        + "WorkCalendarDate Date,"
        + "WorkCalendarDayCount INT(64),"
        + "WorkDayTypeIdNo INT(64),"
        + "PRIMARY KEY(WorkCalendarIdNo),"
        + "FOREIGN KEY(WorkDayTypeIdNo) REFERENCES WorkDayType(WorkDayTypeIdNo)"
        + ")";
```

This is the Department Table

```
    private String department = "CREATE TABLE Department ("
        + "DeptIdNo INT(64) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
        + "DeptName VARCHAR(25),"
        + "PRIMARY KEY(DeptIdNo)"
        + ")";
```

This is the Specialist Table

```
    private String specialist = "CREATE TABLE Specialist ("
        + "SpecIdNo INT(64) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
        + "PrefixIdNo INT(64),"
        + "SpecFirstName VARCHAR(30),"
        + "SpecSurname VARCHAR(35),"
        + "SpecDisplayName VARCHAR(72),"
        + "DeptIdNo INT(64),"
        + "PRIMARY KEY(SpecIdNo),"
        + "FOREIGN KEY(PrefixIdNo) REFERENCES Prefix(PrefixIdNo),"
        + "FOREIGN KEY(DeptIdNo) REFERENCES Department(DeptIdNo)"
        + ")";
```

This is the NewReferral Table

```
    private String newReferral = "CREATE TABLE NewReferral("
        + "NewReferralIdNo INT(64) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
        + "PatientNumber VARCHAR(12),"
        + "NewReferralDate Date,"
        + "DeptIdNo INT(64),"
        + "SpecIdNo INT(64),"
        + "NewReferralMatched BOOLEAN,"
        + "WorkCalendarIdNo INT(64),"
        + "PRIMARY KEY(NewReferralIdNo),"
        + "FOREIGN KEY(DeptIdNo) REFERENCES Department(DeptIdNo),"
        + "FOREIGN KEY(SpecIdNo) REFERENCES Specialist(SpecIdNo),"
        + "FOREIGN KEY(WorkCalendarIdNo) REFERENCES WorkCalendar(WorkCalendarIdNo)"
        + ")";
```

The error is Can't create table 'basque30.newreferral' (errno: 150)

I have tracked the error down to the following line

```
    + "FOREIGN KEY(SpecIdNo) REFERENCES Specialist(SpecIdNo),"
```

Could someone to point out the error of my ways and advise me how to resolve it.

Comment: Are you creating the tables in the order that are listed here?

Comment: Thanks Mihai,In the method that they were being called from, I had them inverted. My Mistake. If you could create a response I'll gladly give it as the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the table referenced already exists.

Answer (score 1):

```
Error no: 150 -- There is a wrong primary key reference in your code.

It's due to a reference FOREIGN KEY(SpecIdNo) REFERENCES Specialist(SpecIdNo)
field does not exist.
```

As you mentioned

```
I have tracked the error down to the following line

+ "FOREIGN KEY(SpecIdNo) REFERENCES Specialist(SpecIdNo),"
                                      ↑
```

Make sure table `Specialist` exists in order to refer as foreign key in another table.
Check the order of table creation.

---

Not related, but might help in future.

If you have admin permission on the server, you may want to start by running the MySQL command

```
SHOW INNODB STATUS
```

for MySQL 5.5

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
```

immediately after receiving the error. This command displays **log info and error details**.